# PHP - Removing XML tags from string

Tags: php, xml, string, plsql

I have string values queried from Oracle DB into PHP strings the with XML around it like below:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><root available-locales="en_US" default-locale="en_US"><Title language-id="en_US">Batman</Title></root>
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><root available-locales="en_US" default-locale="en_US"><Title language-id="en_US">Wonder Woman</Title></root>
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><root available-locales="en_US" default-locale="en_US"><Title language-id="en_US">Fantastic Four</Title></root>
```

I need to remove the XML from the string and just have the titles, like this:

```
Batman
Wonder Woman
Fantastic Four
```

What's the best way to do this?

I was going to try substr but realized I don't know what the ending character is since every title is different. I also tried strip_tags but that didn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use `preg_replace` and capture string between `id="en_US">` and `</Title>` as replacer

```
<?php

$xml = <<<EOF
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><root available-locales="en_US" default-locale="en_US"><Title language-id="en_US">Batman</Title></root>
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><root available-locales="en_US" default-locale="en_US"><Title language-id="en_US">Wonder Woman</Title></root>
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><root available-locales="en_US" default-locale="en_US"><Title language-id="en_US">Fantastic Four</Title></root>
EOF;

$title = preg_replace('#.*id="en_US">(.*?)<.*#', '$1', $xml);
print $title;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php). That will return a [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) from which you could het the `Title` property:

```
$strXml = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><root available-locales="en_US" default-locale="en_US"><Title language-id="en_US">Wonder Woman</Title></root>
XML;

$simpleXmlElement = simplexml_load_string($strXml);
$title = (string)$simpleXmlElement->Title;
echo $title;
```

Or [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($strXml);
echo $doc->getElementsByTagName("Title")[0]->nodeValue;
```

That will give you:

> Wonder Woman